# Cómo funciona el ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: asp.net

Quería saber si alguien me puede orientar un poco en cómo se usa el ScriptManager de asp.

Buscando respuestas en internet encontré este post en stackoverflow en ingles -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169313/what-does-script-manager-control-actually-do) y otras cosas más.

Entiendo que se usa para conectar el cliente con el servidor y trabaja junto con ajax para las respuestas o son parte de un todo.

Y que si quiero usarlo tengo que poner en mi código:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

para que funcione.

A modo de ejemplo quiero ver si entiendo bien esto con un código que tengo (que no lo creé yo):

```
Private Function AperturaLocalVenta() As Boolean
    Dim Terra As New TerraEntities

    Dim Fecha = Now.Date
    'Dim Fecha = DateTime.UtcNow()

    Dim Apertura = (From p In Terra.Tab_Apertura_Local_Venta
                    Where p.Estado = "A" And p.Fecha_Apertura = Fecha
                    Select p).FirstOrDefault

    If Not Apertura Is Nothing Then
        Dim Script As String = "RevisarAperturaTerminal();"

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.NombreUpdatePanel, GetType(Page), "ToggleScript3", Script, True)

        Return True
    Else

        Dim Script As String = "FaltaApertura('Falta apertura de local');"

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.NombreUpdatePanel, GetType(Page), "ToggleScript3", Script, True)

        Return False
    End If


End Function
```

En esta función ver la apertura de un terminal, tengo mi variable para la base de datos, la fecha y genero un resultado de una consulta, si obtengo resultado creo mi variable script y le asigno el nombre de una función que tengo en mi web, en caso contrario hago lo mismo pero con otro nombre.

La función por el lado de la web dice lo siguiente:

```
function RevisarAperturaTerminal() {
$('#TerminalDropDownList').Value(obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Terminal'));


terminal_var = obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Terminal');
var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtTerminalValor");
txtInput.value = terminal_var;

Service2.CompruebaAperturaTerminal($('#TerminalDropDownList').val(), onSuccess_AperturaTerminal, onFail_AperturaTerminal, $('#TerminalDropDownList').val());
//$('#TerminalDropDownList').Enabled(false);
}
```

Esta función toma información de unos imputs y después llama a un Service2 al cual le envía variables.

Dejando hasta acá lo que es código, qué hace mi **ScriptManager** ?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.NombreUpdatePanel, GetType(Page), "ToggleScript3", Script, True)
```

Entiendo que toma el Me.NombreUpdatePanel, este es:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="NombreUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="NombreLabel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        <input id="RecargoCiudadHidden" type="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" value="0" />
        <input id="CreditoClienteDisponibleHidden" type="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" value="0" />
        <input id="CreditoChequeDisponibleHidden" type="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" value="0" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RUTButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Lo que es **GetType(Page), "ToggleScript3",** no sé a que se refiere, supongo que ToggleScript3 es un nombre que yo vendría a asignar, y el *script* es la variable que le mando.

Con esta sentencia le estoy diciendo que la ejecute por el lado del cliente? Sé que es así pero me pierdo en el **para qué** se las envía.

Muchas Gracias